# Unable to redirect users when loggedin ReactNative

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-native, meteor-accounts

This is a login component using Meteor. 
I can't make successful users redirect to another screen 'Home'. 
The error is : 
undefined is not an object (evaluation '_this2.props.navigation.navigate'). 
I have tried to put the redirection into a callback function, but it does the same.

I just edited this post with the full component code.

```
    class SignIn extends Component {

    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        email:'',
        password:'',
        error: null,
        loading: false,
      };
    }


    isValid() {
      const { email, password } = this.state;
      let valid = false;

      if (email.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
        valid = true;
      }

      if (email.length === 0) {
        this.setState({ error: 'You must enter an email address' });
      } else if (password.length === 0) {
        this.setState({ error: 'You must enter a password' });
      }
      return valid;
    }


   onSignIn() {
      const { email, password } = this.state;


       Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            this.setState({ error: error.reason });
            console.log(error, 'erreur dans le sign in')
          }else{
           this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')//HERE
          }
        });
    }

    onCreateAccount() {
      const { email, password } = this.state;


      if (this.isValid()) {
        Accounts.createUser({ email, password }, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            this.setState({ error: error.reason })
          } else {
            this.setState({email:''})
            // temp hack that you might need to use
          };
        });
       }
      }


render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>


...email input here

...password input here

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onSignIn.bind(this)}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: We need to check the entire component code.. and the console is showing an error message?

Comment: I just edited the full code ;-)

Comment: Could you add the index.js and the file where you add your routes to the navigation please? BTW, there is no call to navigation in this component.

Comment: Right, I added it in the onSignIn function! Also here is the StackComponent class StackComponent extends React.Component{


    render(){

      const MainStack = StackNavigator({
        Auth: {screen: SignIn, navigationOptions: {title: 'Login ou SignUp'}},
        Home: {screen: Flat_List , navigationOptions: {title: 'Choisissez votre député'}},
        DeputyProfile:{screen: DeputyProfile, navigationOptions: {title: 'Profile'}},

      },{
      initialRouteName: 'Auth'
      });

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a weird problem like this once

I had to pass the navigation prop through the function call as an argument to use.

```
<MenuItem onPress={() => this.onVehicleCreatePress(this.props.navigation)}>Add New Vehicle</MenuItem>

 onVehicleCreatePress(props) {
    props.navigate('VehicleCreateScreen')
    this.menu.hide();
  }
```